# How to add Path Parameter on http client C#

Tags: c#, rest, http, dotnet-httpclient

How to add Path Parameter on http client C#
URL example
https://testurl/accounts/product/:productid/user/:userid?fields=Attributes

I tried adding with `KeyValuePair` but no luck.

[image]

Comment: url parameters.... try add them over url string

Comment: you can use string concatenation to add paramaters at the end of  the url. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings#:~:text=Concatenation%20is%20the%20process%20of,occurs%20only%20at%20run%20time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string interpolation and concatenation.  I think this is what you are askin for;

```
        int userId = 1;
        string url = $"https://testurl/accounts/product/:productid/user/{userId}";
       // Add here if there is any condtion if() or any loop
        url += "?fields=Attributes";
```